# add_rewrite_rule using custom taxonomy and year

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a CPT called books and a custom taxonomy called genre and need to show in a page all books of a specific term and a specific year.

For that, I created taxonomy-genre.php file and created a `get_posts` query which work fine when the Permalink are disabled. The URL is:

```
index.php?genre=fiction&year=2014
```

Now I'm trying to create a rewrite rule:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'genre/([a-z])/([0-9]{4})/?$',
        'index.php?genre=$matches[1]&year=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

But the website return not found.

Comment: WHY???? `get_posts`

Comment: @PieterGoosen to grab all posts from a specific gender and specific year

Comment: `pre_get_posts` and the default main query loop is the correct way. Will also eliminate pagination issues, is faster and way better for performance

Comment: @PieterGoosen OK I will try. But I can't see how this can solve my rewrite_rule issue.

Comment: It will not solve the rewrite issue, but will solve other issues you will experience once you have the rewrites sorted :-)

Comment: You don't specify a `post_type`.

Comment: @Milo I try with no success.

Comment: Are you flushing permalinks after adding/changing the rule? `var_dump($wp_query)` after it runs to see how query vars are being set and the generated SQL.

Comment: @Milo Yes. Every time I change the rule, I refresh permalinks. /gender/fiction work fine. But /gender/fiction/2014 not.

Comment: `([a-z])` only matches one letter, change it to `([a-z]+)`.